# HTML 5 Camera access & upload file using php

Tags: php, html, file-upload, camera

I am using below code for html 5 camera access and uploading the image to server.

HTML Code

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

upload.php code

```
<?php 
$target_path = "upload/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Problem is When I am testing the code it's showing "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!" . Can anyone help me to figure it out where the problem ?

Below code is working properly for me.

HTML Code :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

PHP code is same as above.

Comment: What is the output from your `move_uploaded_file()`? It's possible that you don't have permissions to put files into your target folder, or some other error. Check your error logs.

Comment: you have to change the permission on "upload/" directory

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IN the first case your file input name is named 'image' when on the second case is named 'uploadedfile'. Your PHP is expecting 'uploadedfile'.

To solve this you need to change your code (first case) to:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
   <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" accept="image/*" capture>  
   <input type="submit" value="Upload">  
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use HTML5 and the camera of the device, there is an HTML5 feature for this:
Exemple:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

from here: https://coderwall.com/p/epwmoa

It's working on chrome for Android (with a Samsung Galaxy S2).

Edit 2022-06-22 following @gtu comment:

> capture attribute only allows user or environment values representing front and back camera respectively.

Comment: I think `capture` attribute only allows `user` or `environment` values representing front and back camera respectively.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture